# Call a .bat file from iMacro / js

Tags: javascript, batch-file, imacros, execute

i am trying to call a batch-file from a iMacro that I created.
I run a .js script, with runs several .iims and shall then execute the
.bat file.

The .bat file removes the first 5 lines from a .txt file and saves it again.
The .txt will be used in the next script run.
- I'm using a for-loop for this -

So my question is:
How can I execute this .bat file from my .js script?
Would it be possible to write a code which deletes the first 5 lines of this specific .txt? (then I wouln't need the .bat)

// I am running Windows 10 and I am using Firefox

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with a txt-file seems to be more preferable in similar cases. Try the script like this:

```
var fileTxt = imns.FIO.openNode("D:\\iMacros\\Datasources\\test.txt");
var lines = imns.FIO.readTextFile(fileTxt).split("\r\n").slice(5).join("\r\n");
imns.FIO.writeTextFile(fileTxt, lines);
```

Note: your txt-file must be in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!